# VBA working with Excel 2013 not working with M365 desktop app

Tags: excel, vba

I have a .xlsm file with a macro working great on a old computer using Excel 2013, but unfortunaly it doesn't work on a new laptop using M365 desktop app. Can you help ?

```
Sub Refresh()
' variable sheetHide is used to see if a sheet is hidden
Dim sheetHide As Boolean

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ' if (sheet visible) then sheetHide is FALSE
        sheetHide = Not Sheets(i).Visible
        
        ' if (sheetHide is TRUE) then we display the sheet
        If (sheetHide) Then
            Sheets(i).Visible = True
        End If
        
        ' we work on the sheet 
        If (Sheets(i).Visible) Then
            Sheets(i).Select
            'If (i = 32) Then
            '    MsgBox "Index " + CStr(i) + " Sheet " + Sheets(i).Name + " Hidden = " + CStr(sheetHide)
            'End If
            Application.Run "ImportWorksheet"
            Calculate
        End If
        
        ' if (sheetHide is TRUE ) then we hide again the sheet
        If (sheetHide) Then
            Sheets(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
    
   ' ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please be specific as to how it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks ok (not great). You should probably share the code of the `ImportWorksheet` procedure which is btw implying that you are dealing with worksheets (opposed to charts which are also part of the `Sheets` collection) so you should replace all those `Sheets` with `Worksheets`. All those parentheses in the `If` clauses are redundant. `Calculate` without a reference doesn't look so good. Also, there are three 'states of sheets visibility': `xlSheetVisible`, `xlSheetHidden`, and `xlSheetVeryHidden`. `IsSheetHidden` instead of `sheetHide` would certainly be a better name for the variable.

Comment: You have just set the visibility to True (`Sheets(i).Visible = True`), and then you are using `If (Sheets(i).Visible) Then`: it's redundant.